# Default values of Ruby variables

Tags: ruby, variables

I need to know the default values of variables in ruby.

```
Global Variables: nil
Instance Variables: ? 
Class Variables: ?
Local Variables: ?
```

I looked [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-types-of-variables/), but all I could find is that global variables have a nil value.

Comment: It's `nil` for all of these.

Comment: you can't use some of them without assignment

Comment: Right, you can't use class variables without initialization (you can use local variables though, e.g. `a = 1 if false; a` won't raise an error, it returns `nil` instead).

Comment: Actually, the question not clear.

Comment: In an interview, the interviewer asked this what are the default values of ruby variables?

Comment: You can answer your question by successively entering, in IRB or PRY, the following: `$a`, `@a` , `a` and `class A; @@A; end`. Enter `B` to see that reference to an undefined constant raises an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You assign a local variable value at first assignment:

```
local = 1
local1 + local # NameError: undefined local variable or method `local1' for main:Object
```

Class variables are similar, if you use them without initialization, you get an error:

```
class A
  @@a
end  
# NameError: uninitialized class variable @@a in A
```

Class instance variables and class variables are `nil` by default:

```
class A
  def self.a
    @a
  end  
  def a
    @a
  end  
end  

> A.a
#=> nil
> A.new.a
#=> nil
```

Comment: The OP is not interested in whether `local1` or `@@a` is defined. The OP wants to know the inventory of the defined variables.

Comment: I don't think so, vide: 'In an interview, the interviewer asked this what are the default values of ruby variables?'

Comment: @mrzasa yes, you can be little clear with scope & default value for local variable with edit

Comment: @ray, you mean the case described in question comment? (hoisting a var defined in a block that is never executed)

Comment: @mrzasa no, it was general suggestion to make answer to elaborate better :)

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to test yourself:

- undefined global variables evaluate to `nil` and generate a warning:

  ```
  defined? $foo
  #=> nil

  $foo
  #=> nil
  # warning: global variable `$foo' not initialized
  ```
- undefined local variables `raise` a `NameError`:

  ```
  defined? foo
  #=> nil

  foo
  # undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)
  ```
- defined but not initialized local variables evaluate to `nil`:

  ```
  defined? foo
  #=> nil

  if false then foo = 42 end

  defined? foo
  #=> 'local-variable'

  foo
  #=> nil
  ```
- undefined instance variables evaluate to `nil` and generate a warning:

  ```
  defined? @foo
  #=> nil

  @foo
  #=> nil
  # warning: instance variable `@foo' not initialized
  ```
- undefined class variables `raise` a `NameError`:

  ```
  defined? @@foo
  #=> nil

  @@foo
  # uninitialized class variable @@foo (NameError)
  ```
- undefined constants `raise` a `NameError`:

  ```
  defined? FOO
  #=> nil

  FOO
  # uninitialized constant FOO (NameError)
  ```

Comment: Whether warning messages are displayed depends on the value of [$VERBOSE](https://mislav.net/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/).